# how to calculate maxtx on contract tokens?

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, evm, honeypot

I want to ask, is it possible to calculate max tx + max wallet by transferring tokens? I have tried transferring tokens by manipulating slots, but there is a problem with the TO & FROM address so it does not pass the max tx/max wallet filter [see code contracts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIDN3.png). Is there another way to get the max tx amount without using ABI accurately?